# How do you run tests serially in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2015

I am using NUnit 3.5.0. According to [this page](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallel-Test-Execution), if you have multiple test assemblies, tests are *automatically* run in parallel *by default*.

It goes on to tell you how to can limit the number of parallel processes from the command line. But how would you turn off parallel processing from within Visual Studio?

> **Background:** I have 15 different test assemblies (over 6500 tests), and it would not be practical to combine them into a single assembly just for the sake of making them run serially. Several of the tests have some shared state that needs to be cleaned up before the next test can be run. I just want to run tests serially like it was done in NUnit 2.6, but I cannot downgrade because I need to support .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested out any of the below, but this is what I *think* happens.

The NUnit Test Adapter actually runs tests 'in process' - which involves no parallelisation of assemblies. The page you've linked to refers to the NUnit Engine, which is the underlying library used by the adapter. The adapter specifies the 'run in process' mode to the engine.

I imagine this is because VS calls one process per assembly - which I'm not sure the NUnit engine would be too happy with if it was using external processes. The NUnit Engine is built with the belief that it is controlling all processes, rather than something else (here: VS) - invoking multiple instances of the engine.

So instead, I think you need to control VS's parallelisation. That's managed via a [.runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx#example) - try setting `MaxCpuCount` to 1.